# If regexes are methods, which class they correspond to?

Tags: oop, raku

Regexes are actually Methods:

```
say rx/foo/.^mro # ((Regex) (Method) (Routine) (Block) (Code) (Any) (Mu))
```

In that case, it means that they can act on self and are part of a class. What would that class be? My hunch is that it's the Match class and that they are actually acting on $/ (which they actually are). Any other way of formulating this?

Comment: It is my understanding that a `Regex` is a method that **always** expects `$/` to be passed to it.  Conversely, if one writes a method to be used as regex, it should expect `$/` to be passed as the first parameter.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen as first parameter or as self? Said otherwise, if they are methods, what self would they act upon?

Comment: As the first parameter, aka `method foo($/) { ... }`.  Note that you can just specify `$/` as the first parameter for convenience.  I think they'd be methods in the Grammar that is being parsed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A method does not have to correspond with any class:

```perl6
my method bar () { say self, '!' }

bar 'Hello World'; # Hello World!


my regex baz { :ignorecase 'hello world' }

'Hello World' ~~ /<baz>/;
'Hello World' ~~ &baz;
&baz.ACCEPTS('Hello World'); # same as previous line

# baz 'Hello World';
```

---

By default methods, and by extension regexes have a `has` relationship with whatever class they are declared inside of.

```perl6
class Foo {
        method bar () { say self, '!' }
  # has method bar () { say self, '!' }

        regex  baz    { :ignorecase 'hello world' }
  # has regex  baz () { :ignorecase 'hello world' }
}
```

---

A regex does need some requirements fulfilled by whatever it's invocant is.

By just running it as a subroutine, it tells you the first one:

```perl6
my regex baz { :ignorecase 'hello world' }

baz 'Hello World';
```

```
No such method '!cursor_start' for invocant of type 'Str'
  in regex baz at <unknown file> line 1
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Usually a regex is declared inside of a class declared with `grammar`.

```perl6
grammar Foo {
}

say Foo.^mro;
# ((Foo) (Grammar) (Match) (Capture) (Cool) (Any) (Mu))
```

So the requirements are likely fulfilled by `Grammar`, `Match`, or `Capture` in this case.

It could also be from a role that gets composed with it.

```perl6
say Foo.^roles.map(*.^name);
# (NQPMatchRole)
```

There is even more reason to believe that it is `Match` or `Capture`

```perl6
my regex baz {
    ^
    { say 'baz was called on: ', self.^name }
}
&baz.ACCEPTS(''); # baz was called on: Match
```

```perl6
my regex baz ( $s ) {
    :ignorecase
    "$s"
}
baz Match.new(orig => 'Hello World'), 'hello';
# ｢Hello｣
```

I see no reason someone couldn't do that themselves in a normal class though.

---

Note that `$/` is just a variable. So saying it is passed to a regex is a misunderstanding of the situation.

```perl6
my regex baz ( $/ ) {
    :ignorecase
    "$/"
}
'Hello World' ~~ /<baz('hello')>/;
# ｢Hello｣
#  baz => ｢Hello｣
```

It would be more accurate to say that when calling a regex from inside of another one, the current `$/` is used as the invocant to the method/regex.
(I'm not entirely sure this is actually what happens.)

So the previous example would then be sort-of like this:

```perl6
'Hello World' ~~ /{ $/.&baz('hello') }/;
```

Comment: From your first example, it simply looks like self is just an alias for the first, implicit, argument, right?

Answer (score 9):

Ultimately, all regexes expect to receive an invocant of type `Match` or some subclass of `Match`. In Perl 6, an invocant is simply the first argument, and is not special in any other way.

Those regexes declared with `rule`, `token` or `regex` within a package will be installed as methods on that package. Most typically, they are declared in a `grammar`, which is nothing more than a `class` whose default parent is `Grammar` rather than `Any`. `Grammar` is a sub-type of `Match`.

```
grammar G {}.^mro.say # ((G) (Grammar) (Match) (Capture) (Cool) (Any) (Mu))
```

It's thus quite natural to see these as just methods, but with a body written in a different language. In fact, that's precisely what they are.

It's a little harder to see how the anonymous regexes are methods, in so far as they don't get installed in the method table of any type. However, if we were to write:

```
class C {
    method foo() { 42 }
}
my $m = anon method () { self.foo }
say C.$m()
```

Then we see that we can resolve symbols on the invocant through `self`, even though this method is not actually installed on the class `C`. It's the same with anonymous regexes. The reason this matters is that assertions like `<ident>`, `<.ws>`, `<?before foo>` and friends are actually compiled into method calls.

Thus, anonymous regexes being methods, and thus treating their first argument as an invocant, is what allows the various builtin rules, which are declared on `Match`, to be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

This explanation combines what I think Brad++ and Jonathan++ just taught me, with what I thought I already knew, with what I discovered as I dug further.

(My original goal was to directly explain Brad's mysterious `No such method '!cursor_start'` message. I've failed for now, and have instead just filed [a bug report](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3025), but here's what else I ended up with.)

## Methods

Methods are designed to work naturally in classes. Indeed a method declaration without a scope declarator assumes [`has`](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/has) -- and a `has` declaration belongs inside a class:

```
method bar {} # Useless declaration of a has-scoped method in mainline
```

But in fact methods also work fine as either:

- `sub`s (i.e. *not* behaving as an object oriented method at all); or
- methods for [prototype-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) (i.e. object orientation, but without classes).

What really makes methods methods is that they are routines with an ["invocant"](https://docs.perl6.org/language/classtut#index-entry-invocant). An invocant is a special status first parameter that:

- Is implicitly inserted into the method's [signature](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature) if not explicitly declared. If a method is declared inside a class, then the type constraint is that class, otherwise it's `Mu`:

```
        class foo { my method bar {} .signature .say } # (foo: *%_)
                    my method bar {} .signature .say   # (Mu: *%_)
```

- Is a required positional. Thus:

```
        my method bar {}
        bar # Too few positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 0
```

- Is always aliased to `self`. Thus:

```
        my method bar { say self }
        bar 42 # 42
```

- Is occasionally explicitly declared by specifying it as the first parameter in a signature and following it with a colon (`:`). Thus:

```
        my method bar (Int \baz:) { say baz } 
        say &bar.signature; # (Int \baz: *%_)
        bar 42;             # 42
        bar 'string';       # Type check failed in binding to parameter 'baz'
```

## Regexes

Focusing just on the invocant perspective, regexes are methods that take/expect a match object as their invocant.

A regex is typically called in three somewhat different scenarios:

- **By direct use.** For example `my regex foo { . }; say 'a' ~~ &foo; # ｢a｣` (or just `say 'a' ~~ / . /; # ｢a｣`, but I'll only cover the essentially identical named example to simplify my explanation). This translates to `say &foo.ACCEPTS: 'a'`. This in turn is [implemented by this code in Rakudo](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/cbb9034a08b0423f40d8a070f1c24a9ed7e74527/src/core/Regex.pm6#L28-L40). As you can see, this calls the regex `foo` with the invocant `Match.'!cursor_init'(...)` -- [which runs this code](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/a917b0051707f94207676033b1bebb369a7a5a7e/src/QRegex/Cursor.nqp#L346) without `:build`. The upshot is that `foo` gets a new `Match` object as its invocant.
- **By way of the `Grammar` class's `.parse` method.** [The `.parse` method](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/5caf7aafa4b606081d171645551fc06e95daf3c3/src/core.c/Grammar.pm6#L3-L30) creates a new instance of the grammar and then calls the top "rule" (`rule`/`token`/`regex`/`method`) on that new grammar object. Note that a `Grammar` is a sub-class of `Match`; so, just as with the first scenario, the rule/regex is being passed an as-yet-empty match object. If the top rule matches, the new grammar/match object will be returned by the call to `.parse`. (Otherwise it'll return `Nil`.)
- **By way of one of the above.** The top rule in a grammar will typically contain calls to lower level rules/tokens/regexes/methods. Likewise, a free standing rule/regex may contain calls to other rules/regexes. Each such call will involve creating another new grammar/match object that becomes the invocant for the nested call. If the nested call matches, and it's a capturing call, then the new grammar/match object is added to the higher level grammar/match object.